# MdxScript(Model) cslculation error in measure : A table of multiple values was supplied where single value was expected

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

İ want to find sufficient stock according to sale.

```
Measure =
VAR _date = VALUES(dateofdata)

VAR opening_date = VALUES('Stores' [Opening date])

VAR dayfornewstores = _date-opening_date

VAR _days = 28

VAR avg_sales = IF(opening_date<28,[TotalSales]/opening_date,[TotalSales]/_days)

VAR qual_days = [TotalStocks]/avg_sales

RETURN qual_days
```

When I use this measure in table for each store it is success. But when I want all of my stores number of days to qualify for sale in card visual there is error. How can I solve it?

Comment: Not sure which `date` you are expecting from `VALUES(dateofdata)`, which seems all round just wrong. Why are you creating a `dayfornewstores` variable at all? It is not used. Your `opening_date` variable supplies a list of values, but you use it as if it is a single value - and for this to work on multiple stores you need to completely rewrite this.

Comment: _date is days of sale, and daydornewstores is for which stores opening date is less than 28 from today.

Comment: I think you need to aggregate your `VALUES(dateofdata)` to actually provide a single value instead of a table of multiple values.